# My specific Flutter project has problem with some packages

Tags: android, flutter, package

I have a specific flutter project that has error on some packages i added like the following:

on **image_picker** package issue - when running *ImagePicker.pickImage*:

`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)`

on **url_launcher** package issue - when running *canLaunch(url)*:

`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)`

on **plaid** package issue:

`Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/webview`

Note:

- I have tried to import those packages on my previous projects on the same machine, and it works just fine.
- Tested this project to build *iOS* and it works fine so the problem most likely is on *android* build.
- Done **flutter clean**, **flutter upgrade**, uninstall/reinstall app on device, tested on other android device/emulator but doesn't solved the problem.
- Tried to run both on Android Studio and VS Code, but still gives the same error.
- changed to flutter **stable** channel, and Still got no luck.

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.16.4-pre.69, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.16.4-pre.69 at C:\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 19e7db585d (5 days ago), 2020-04-01 11:16:01 -0700
    • Engine revision c9506cb8e9
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.18.0 eea9717938)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\mikay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\mikay\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Samsung Galaxy S8 • 192.168.175.101:5555 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

*pubspec.yaml*

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.6.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  relative_scale: ^1.0.5
  rxdart: ^0.23.1
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
  dio: ^3.0.9
  pretty_dio_logger: ^1.1.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
  flushbar: ^1.10.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  flutter_advanced_networkimage: ^0.7.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.4
  decimal: ^0.3.0
  plaid: ^1.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.19+9
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

*build.gradle(app)*

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.app.example"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

*build.gradle (project-level)*

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you stopped the application and relaunch it entirely? using hot reload could be related to this.

Comment: @encubos as what's on my note: *Done flutter clean, flutter upgrade, uninstall/reinstall app on device, tested on other android device/emulator but doesn't solved the problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The reason is that I added the **flutter_facebook_login** and did not do its additonal setup which is to add this code on **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

thus, It mess up all packages that initiate an external views like *camera*, *file manager*, *web view*, etc..